# Finding double lines in SAS table

Tags: sql, sas, duplicates, grouping, proc-sql

I have received a table with double data lines in it, which I want to visualize. I tried writing something like this:

```
proc sql; create table double_lines as
select *, count(*) as c
from table 
group by *
having c>1
;quit;
```

But I can't group by *, is there another way of doing this? I can imagine that simply stating all existing columns is a solution, but that is going to take a while. Is there a more practical solution?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is probably to use the `dupout` command to a `proc sort`:

```
data have;
length first_col 8. second_col third_col $20;
input first_col second_col $ third_col $;
datalines;
1234     Insurance   A
1234     Insurance   A
1234     Auto        B
5678     Claims      B
5678     Claims      B
5678     New         C
;
run;

proc sort data=have noduprecs dupout=want;
   by _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `group by *` is not valid in SQL.

You must have something as your `group by` variable. I take @Jeppe Rømer Juul 's data as sample.

```
data have;
length first_col  8. second_col third_col $20 hashid $64.;
input first_col second_col $ third_col $;
hashid = md5(cats(of _all_));
datalines;
1234     Insurance   A
1234     Insurance   A
1234     Auto        B
5678     Claims      B
5678     Claims      B
5678     New         C
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  create table want as 
  select *, count(*) as count from have group by hashid having count(*)>1;
quit;
```

In general, `hashid` is a uniqueid of its row and its value depends on the values of all other variables on this row.